# Как спарсить динамичный HTML элемент <li> если они все одинаковы?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, lxml, aiogram-2.x

```
dp.message_handler(text='Столовая')
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    url = 'https://foodmonitoring.ru/13188/food'
    headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
                   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    reg = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reg, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find('div', class_="col-12 col-md align-self-center")
    stolovaya = block.find_all(itemprop="menuListItemLink")
    for item in stolovaya:
        item_text = item.text
        item_href = "https://foodmonitoring.ru" + item.get("href")
        print(f"{item_text}: {item_href}")
```

Всем привет. На данный момент парсит весь список xlsx который есть в блоке (div). В этом блоке есть html элементы "li" в которых есть нужная мне ссылка, как сделать так, что бы парсил только третий элемент "li" сверху? Помогите пожалуйста..

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `stolovaya` у вас хранится список всех html-элементов, которые были распаршены. Вы можете получить нужный элемент просто обратившись по индексу. В приведенном вами коде, третий элемент `li` можем получить так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(text='Столовая')
async def help(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    url = 'https://foodmonitoring.ru/13188/food'
    headers = {'Accept': '*/*',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    reg = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reg, 'lxml')
    block = soup.find('div', class_="col-12 col-md align-self-center")
    stolovaya = block.find_all(itemprop="menuListItemLink")

    item = stolovaya[2]
    item_text = item.text
    item_href = "https://foodmonitoring.ru" + item.get("href")

    print(f"{item_text}: {item_href}")
```

Comment: как все оказывается просто...... Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!!!!